# Pulling text string from HTML span if other tag criteria is met

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

I am loading a webpage through a java script with the intention of pulling a single string value from that website's HTML source code to use elsewhere in my script.  So the website has multiple  row containers that follow this basic format:

```
<tr>

<td align="left">     
<span class="criteria1">      
<script>document.write("INFO I WANT");</script>INFO I WANT        
</span>
</td>

<td align="left"><a href="http://www.example.com/1234/" title="Directory Criteria 1234">1234</a>        
</td>

<td align="left">         
<div class="criteria2" data-value="100" title="1642"></div>       
</td>

<td align="left">   
<span class="criteria3" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:10px;">North</span> 
</td>

</tr>
```

The site has many of these row containers that I am not interested in, and a handful that I am interested in.  So, I want to check each row container to see if the following criteria is met (they are in my above example):

1. There must be a span element with class="criteria1"
2. There must be a an anchor tag  with "1234" somewhere in the title= attribute value
3. There must be a div element with class="criteria2" AND data-value="100"
4. There must be another span element with class="criteria3" and "North" in whatever field you see it in my example

If these criteria are met, I want to pull the "INFO I WANT" string, and save it to a variable in my script. We could pull this from within the script tags or from where it appears after the  tag... what would this be, the innerHTML content of this specific span tag?

As you have gathered from this point, I am new to javascript, so I apologize in advance if any of this is stupid, easy, and/or unclear.  I have done a lot of digging to try to figure out how to do this, but after a day and a half of testing with little progress I have reached a breaking point of sorts. Obviously, it will require a loop to go over each  container, and then (I am guessing) use the getElementsBy methods to check the criteria.

Pardon my lack of formal training/vocabulary, and thanks in advance for any help.  Just by trolling StackOverflow, you all have already helped me a GREAT deal in other ventures!!  And please, by all means, correct any misuse of terminology above.  Knowing the right way to express these ideas will help me greatly in future research to find answers to my questions.

Comment: Complex queries of the DOM are exactly the kind of thing jQuery was made for.  Can you use jQuery or do you need vanilla Javascript?

Comment: @blurd, perhaps jquery would be the simplest most straight forward approach, though I am not particularly familiar with it.  I'm going to review your suggestion below and do some testing.  It looks promising.  Thanks for the quick (and thorough) feedback.  I will report back...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution, but it should set you on the right path.  Isolate each of the criteria into a method you can pass the row to.  That way, you can change criteria easily later on.

```
// get all rows
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  currentRow,
  i = 0;

for (; i < trs.length; i++) {
  currentRow = trs[i];

  if (hasClassCriteria1(currentRow)) {
    if (hasAnchorWithTitle(currentRow)) {
      if (hasDivWithCriteria2(currentRow)) {
        console.log('continue checks until you find what you want...');
      }
    }
  }
}



// There must be a span element with class="criteria1"
function hasClassCriteria1 (row) {
  var spans = row.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    i;

  // Do any of these spans have the class "criteria1"?
  for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    matched = spans[i].classList.contains('criteria1');
    if (matched) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

// There must be a an anchor tag with "1234" somewhere in the title= attribute value
function hasAnchorWithTitle (row) {
  var a = row.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (/1234/.test(a[i].getAttribute('title'))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

// There must be a div element with class="criteria2" AND data-value="100"
function hasDivWithCriteria2 (row) {
  var divs = row.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].classList.contains('criteria2')) {
      if (divs[i].getAttribute('data-value') == 100) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### with jQuery

If you can use jQuery, the selectors will be very easy and expressive.

```
// There must be a span element with class="criteria1"
tr = tr.has('span.criteria1');

// There must be a an anchor tag with "1234" somewhere in the title= attribute value
tr = tr.has('a[title*="1234"]');

// There must be a div element with class="criteria2" AND data-value="100"
tr = tr.has('div.criteria2[data-value="100"]');

// There must be another span element with class="criteria3" and "North" in whatever field you see it in my example
return $('span.criteria3', tr).html() === 'North';
```

You can see the full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BnJLS/).  It finds all the rows that match your criteria, then loops through them, alerting with the value you're seeking.

jQuery is your friend.  There is a ton of documentation and [it's easy to get started](http://jquery.com/).  Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you're just trying to learn.